# How do I nest if then statements with select statements including other if then statements?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm fairly new to SQL and can't figure out how to combine several `if .. then` statements.

What is the right syntax for this?

I'm using SQL Server Management Studio 2017.
I've tried to combine `if... else if..statements` and I tried using case statements, but I always get lost in the nesting of the statements.

I have several condtions whom have to be met before I can execute some sort of calculation.

It should be something like this:

```
If CalculationMethod = x 

and if (Price * coefficient) < Amount

then CalculatedAmount = Amount

else CalculatedAmount = (Price * coefficient)
```

Where `Amount` has it's own if statements:

```
Amount =

If Category = a and DistanceFrom <= Distance >= DistanceUntill then take amount from that particular cell

If Category = b and DistanceFrom <= Distance >= DistanceUntill then take amount from that particular cell

If Category = c and DistanceFrom <= Distance >= DistanceUntill then take amount from that particular cell
```

In this case, `Amount` is a cell in a table with columns `DistanceFrom`, `DistanceUntill`, `a`, `b` and `c`.

`CalculationMethod` and `Coefficient` are columns in another table.
`Price` is a column in third table.

In the end I want the `CalculatedAmount` based on the `Amount`, `Price` and `Coefficient`.

Does this make any sense? Does anyone has an idea on how to tackle this?

Comment: Better for us to help if you post the table schema, sample data and the expected result - with any query you have already tried

Comment: If you get lost in nesting it means you are trying to do the wrong thing. Perhasp you need *different* queries, or different columns in the results. The way you describe what you want though is rather confusing. Post the table's schema, some test data, expected results and what you tried.

Comment: For example, if `DistanceFrom <= Distance >= DistanceUntill ` appear in every case, perhaps they *shouldn't* appear at all? Perhaps `WHERE` should only allow matching rows?

Comment: I'm not following logic. Most importantly: "take amount from that particular cell." **What** particular cell? A database doesn't have cells; it's not a spreadsheet. Please provide structure, enough sample data to represent every possible logic branch, and desired output.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an IF...THEN...ELSE type of scenario I think the right direction would be to use a CASE statement such as:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN CalculationMethod = x AND ((Price * coefficient) < Amount) THEN Amount
        ELSE (Price * coefficient) END CalculatedAmount
```

You can read about it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

An IIF clause works very well when there is only one decision branch, but if you have multiple things to choose from the CASE statement is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT IIF(CalculationMethod = x and Price * coefficient < Amount, Amount, Price * coefficient) as CalculatedAmount 
      FROM aTable
```